# Update Core Data with JSON Key Value ( id )

Tags: ios, iphone, json, core-data

I am having a problem with updating the core data.
i am downloading the data in the background thread  comparing with the identifier in core data and count but am having trouble to update now i want to check the identifier present in Core data with JSON Response and if id is present in the JSON Response leave it and if not present in JSON Response (That means That record has been removed in Server side)

Here in this code am checking id is present in core data or not  and now i want to check the id is present in json or not to update the records

Any help will be great appreciate thanks in advance
please check the code how am storing the data in to core data

```
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayData count]; i++) {
        NSNumber * idNum = [arrayData objectAtIndex:i][@"id"];
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Deal"];
        [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier == %@",idNum]];
        [request setFetchLimit:1];
        NSUInteger count = [_managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if (count == NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR");
        }else if (count == 0) {
            Deal * dealsEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Deal" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
            NSString * name  = [arrayData objectAtIndex:i][@"name"];
            dealsEntity.nameAttribute = name;
            dealsEntity.identifier = idNum;
            [appDelegate saveContext];
        }
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateData:) withObject:_myArray waitUntilDone:YES];
    }

- (void) updateData:(NSArray *)yourData {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Deal" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    yourData = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    self.myArray = yourData;
    [listTableView reloadData];
}
```

I have tried this with updating or deleting the records from coredata

```
for (int d = 0; d < [_myArray count]; d++) {
        Deal * deal = (Deal*)_myArray[d];
        NSNumber * identifier = [deal identifier];
        if ([identifier isEqualToNumber:[[arrayData objectAtIndex:d] valueForKey:@"id"]] ) {
            NSLog(@"equal %d",d);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Kill it ");
        }
    }
```

but here the problem is Coredata has 115 records when checking with json but json will have only 114 records and it returns crash

Comment: Whats the issue you are facing with this?

Comment: Right now am checking the iD from JSON and if it is not present in core data it has to store the above code is working fine

Comment: But now i want to update the Data base by checking the Coredata identifier is present in json and update the database

Comment: for example one record delete from json response in future so core data has to check the json response also

Comment: i want some code for updating the data in core data

Answer (score 0):

As you have the identifier into your database you just need to change your code little bit

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Deal" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier == %@",idNum]];
[request setFetchLimit:1];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

// check the count 

if([results count] == 1) {
   // Update your coredata object
} else {
   // Create new object 
}
```

Comment: for example now core data having 100 records and for json side one record is deleted that means i have to delete the one record in core data

Comment: How do you decide that you want to create new data row or want to delete it?

Comment: if([results count] == 1) { in this place you told me to update the data by checking the CoreData with JSON

Comment: Yes, it means data is available into coredata with that id, you can't use the same JSON for adding and updating the database and deleting too.

Comment: so for this i have to create a fetch request and get id present in coredata and check with the Json right

Comment: Yes, but instead of getting count, you should get the actual object so you can modify it or delete it as needed.

Comment: so you mean to get identifier instead of count or results

Comment: I mean get the actual object with that id!

Comment: You can handle it however you like!

Comment: so how can i delete the record do i need to create one more for loop and check with the json

Comment: in the place results count == 1 i do i need to create one more fetch request with deal entity and create the loop there and delete the records there

Comment: there is simple logical thing which you are missing, just fetch all the row from coredata and check with your jason loop and add those which id is not available into your jason and delete them

Comment: I tried with this by adding duplicate row in my sqlite file so in the next run it has to find thad duplicate right but it is returning me array beyond 115 like this please see the updated code the last code..

Comment: JSON & Core Data have 100 records for example if 1 record is deleted in json then in this case for loop is breaking returning me crash beyond...

Comment: You can do one thing, make the array of all the jason id and all the coredata object id and using the NSSet removeObjectsInArray you will get the array of not available object which you can remove from coredata

Comment: can you give me sample

Comment: i got all core data identifiers in to an array and also json array is ready what i do now

Comment: Go to this link and you can get common and uncommon id http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246273/compare-two-arrays-and-get-the-common-items

Comment: its given me common id's

Comment: core data have 116 records json have 115 records so it returned me 115 common records id's now how can i get than only record so that i can delete the record

Comment: this was given me simple solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649198/objective-c-how-to-compare-arrays-and-extract-the-difference

Comment: can you help me doing with NSDate

Comment: and now am getting the uncommon records how can i delete those records please help me with the coding